# Friedel Crafts Acylation: Reaction of acyl halide with catalyst

Tags: organic-chemistry

To form an electrophile for this reaction to occur, the acyl halide interacts with the catalyst. However, on reviewing the conditions for the reaction, I have encountered that the 2 equivalence of the acyl halide is required.

In the case of the acyl chloride, there are 2 ways the acyl chloride can react with the catalyst.

[image]

(Sorry for the sloppy diagram)

In the case of the first reaction, Cl is good leaving group, but what is the reasoning of the second reaction to occur?

Comment: Strength of the O-Al bond is a significant factor

Comment: @Waylander, could it be that Al has vacant p-orbital where the 1 lone pair from oxygen atom is donated, to create a bond forming the adduct (similar as in BF3, since both are in the same group)?

Comment: That is exactly what occurs